# how to get values in get_context_data

Tags: django

Hi everyone My model has this attribute

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  TYPES_CHOICES = ( 
    ('none', 'not specified'),
    ('v', 'By Visit'),
    ('p', 'By Patient'),
  )
  app_config = AppHookConfigField(HealthConfig)
  url = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250)
  count = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250)
  start = models.CharField(blank=True, default='', max_length=250)
  status = models.CharField(choices=TYPES_CHOICES, max_length=10, default='')
```

in my view I have a generic List view like this

```
class IndexView(AppConfigMixin, generic.ListView):
  model = Entry
  template_name = 'health/index.html'

  def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(IndexView, self).get_queryset()
    return qs.namespace(self.namespace)

  def get_context_data (self, **kwargs): 
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    values_to_pass = context['object_list'].values('url', 'count', 'start')
    context['object_list'] = values_to_pass
    print values_to_pass
    return context
```

How to get the value `url`,`count` and `start` to join in one value and pass the the html file

`final= url + count + start`

now `print values_to_pass` return a empty list `[]`

Any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to guarantee that your `context['object_list']` has your objects, so please check that.

If you want to concatenate your `url`, `count` and `start` you could use the [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) function with the `flat` argument and join them so you have one single string, i.e.:

```
final = '-'.join(context['object_list'].values_list('url', 'count', 'start', flat=True))
```

This would result in a `-` separated string, like `url_val-count_val-start_val`.